# Data simulations for SVM : study of parameters

Tags: r, classification, svm, simulation, parameterization

I'm studying SVM for classification. The first step of my work consists in making a data simulation in order to study the influence of the cost parameter C, the choice of the kernel, for examples.
Do you have any advices in order to have a good study of those parameters ? Which laws to simulate? My point is to understand which kernel use under some circumstances, how to adapt the cost parameter...
I hope you understand what i'm trying to do : i want to understand what are the influences of the parameters on the classification depending of the see of datas i have. For example i saw on internet , a triangle, with points from class A inside the triangle, and points from class B outside the triangle. The shape was like a reverse parabola, so the use of the gaussian kernel, with a good value of C, was adapted. I looking for those kind of simulations.
Thank you for your answers !

Comment: You might some inspiration in the documentation of the sklearn library for python. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html

Comment: I published a couple of videos regarding the influence of various parameters (degree, bandwith, cost) on the classification boundary of SVMs, like this one : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsR3pNj_z9I hope this helps to have an intuition!